# Integral of a geometric Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I would like to compute $G$ defined as follows 
$$G(t):= \exp(-\int _0^t h_s~ ds )$$ with $h$ being a geometric Brownian Motion.

For that I would need first to compute $$\int_0^t e^{(\mu-\sigma^2/2)s+ \sigma W_s }~ ds$$
and know its law.

All I could figure out (that was not much) is that one can obtain all the moments by deriving the Laplace Transform and making the Laplace coefficient tends to zero witch is pretty straightforward

Could someone give me a help with that ? Any advice is appreciated.

> Note that this question is not a duplicate since my question is to
>   compute the exponential of an integral of a geometric
>   Brownian motion and to compute the integral of the GBM itself.There is no expected value involveld

Many thanks

Comment: Note that this question is not a duplicate since my question is to compute the exponential of an integral of a geometric Brownian motion and to compute the integral of the GBM itself.There is no expected value involveld

Comment: @Did: Could you please explain me how the question you judge duplicate of mine completely answer my question? Otherwise it would be nice to reopen it. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please explain me what "to compute a random variable" exactly means?

Comment: I meat obtain an analytic formula for that

Comment: What would be an analytic formula for a random variable? Sorry but do you have an idea of what you are talking about here?

Comment: Indeed I was not clear at all with my comment. Sorry for that. I would like to know if the law of this random variable is trivially known. If there is the case what is this law? Has its distribution a "simple" analytic formula ?

Comment: When, as here, the distribution has no simple closed form, one turns to transforms such as the Laplace transform of the distribution, hoping that they have a simple closed form. This is what happens here, which is why your question is a duplicate.